# How to access internal API after jdk 17?

Tags: java, java-17

As we know, jdk 17 has a new feature: Encapsulating the Java runtime internals. It made developers cannot access jdk internal API anymore even through reflection.

Now, do we have any methods to access jdk internal api?

Comment: The real question is: why do you need to do that?

Comment: @Olivier because I see Lombok can access the internal api such as com.sun.tools. I am curious about that how Lombok can do that.

Comment: See how [Lombok did it](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/commit/7069c7e90377952ae7c9a7dfd6786205dfe7ec5f) or how [Eclipse Window builder did it by using the Burningwave library](https://github.com/eclipse/windowbuilder/issues/45).

Comment: @howlger but this class can directly import the internal api such as com.sun.tools: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/javac/apt/LombokProcessor.java

Comment: Yes, but this works only with Java 17 or higher (or Java 16 without VM argument for old behavior) and a Lombok version containing the mentioned change.

Comment: @howlger but I am using jdk 17, I cannot directly import com.sun.tools

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You are talking about internals of the system library which are not API anymore for reasons, right? So don't use it anymore. Do also not use something like `--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED` to make `System.out.println(com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements.class);` compileable. Migrate your code instead of hacking the Java VM. Unfortunately, you didn't tell your [root problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @howlger but I wanna know how Lombok can do that. I try to follow the source code of Lombok to do that just for learning reason but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try reflection the way in the mentioned change and not the old way? Please tell your root problem and show your code.